# Django, alter username field of User model

Tags: python, django

I wish to add a maxlength of 255 characters for username field in django User model. I would also like to increase the maxlength of first_name and last_name fields. I have looked through lot many posts saw monkeypatching as an option but I am unable to understand it. I was wondering if its possible to write a custom migration file and apply it somehow. Is it possible and if yes some guidance on how to achieve it would be great.

Note: It might seem like its a duplicate but lot of posts that I have found on SO are about adding a new field which can be achieved using `User.add_to_class()`. I intend to alter maxlength.

Comment: You should explore the option of [using a custom user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model) - as doing what you are suggesting will break on a django upgrade.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid the thing is that I am through with project and now the client wants support for larger username and name fields. Hence I am not looking at an option that will put me through a lot of changes. I assume if I use a custom user model I will have to make necessary changes in the code as well right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a "large" change required to your Django project, and probably something that should have been done at the beginning rather than the end. As someone that's experienced migrations breaking on User models on production systems I agree with [@Burhan Khalid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/790387/burhan-khalid) - leave the `contrib.auth.models.User` model as it is.

First let's look at the warnings in the documentation, from [Substituting a custom User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#auth-custom-user):

> Changing this setting after you have tables created is not supported
>   by makemigrations and will result in you having to manually fix your
>   schema, port your data from the old user table, and possibly manually
>   reapply some migrations.

I understand that you want to "just increase" the length of these fields, but this isn't a trivial change, or one that migrations was "meant" to deal with. The "Django-way" to solve this problem is to add a custom User model that fulfils the new requirements. Unfortunately, this means that you'll have to handle a migration manually if you have existing user data on a production server. The standard instructions on [Customizing authentication in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/) will help you out.

The benefits you'll receive, which hopefully will pay off the hard work, are:

- Project code is protected against any upgrades. The default User model won't have any customisations.
- Project code will conform to the "Django-way" making it easier for other developers and team members to work with in the future.

I understand that's probably not what you want to hear, but I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I guess I will use custom user model after reading it!